# Executing query inside spring batch processor

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

In my project I need to execute a query inside *Spring Batch* processor in order to validate some field.

How can I do that?

### EDIT: Adding sources:

This is definition of step:

```
@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<CaricoDTO> step1Writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<CaricoDTO, CaricoDTO>chunk(10).reader(multiResourceItemReader())
            .processor(processorStep1()).writer(step1Writer).build();

}
```

This is definition of `multiResourceItemReader`:

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<CaricoDTO> multiResourceItemReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<CaricoDTO> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<CaricoDTO>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexesToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Resource[] inputResources = null;
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    try {
        inputResources = patternResolver.getResources(inputPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(step1Reader());
    resourceItemReader.setComparator(new FileComparator());
    return resourceItemReader;
}
```

This is `step1Reader`:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<CaricoDTO> step1Reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<CaricoDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<CaricoDTO>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<CaricoDTO>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|") {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { ..... });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CaricoDTO>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(CaricoDTO.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

This is my processor bean:

```
@Bean
public CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1 processorStep1() {
    CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1 processorStep1 = new CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1();
    return processorStep1;
}
```

This is my processor definition:

```
public class CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<CaricoDTO, CaricoDTO> {

    private String fileName;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1.class);
    
    @Override
    public CaricoDTO process(CaricoDTO carico) throws Exception {

        carico.setDataCaricamento(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        carico.setFileName(carico.getResource().getFilename());
        return carico;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

}
```

And this is my writer:

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<CaricoDTO> step1Writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<CaricoDTO>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql(....)
            .dataSource(dataSource).build();
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? How you project / components setup look like? A simple straightforward way would be to use a `JdbcTemplate` but there might other / better ways of doing so.

Comment: @tmarwen I have a reader reading from a csv file, a processor and a writer writing into db but i have to discard some records due to values not present in domain tables. I'm using h2 as data persistence

Comment: I still don't get the total picture. Could you add the minimal reproducible code from your code base? How are you already performing reads / writes, are using the *Spring Batch* `ItemReader` / `ItemWriter`?

Comment: @tmarwen I have added infos to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given little details in the main OP, I am assuming that the general solution would be accepted.

Given a classic *Spring Batch* project setup, you should have access to a `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` bean connected to the target `javax.sql.DataSource` that you can simply inject in one of your batch collaborator components:

- `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader`
- `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter`
- `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor`

Assuming you need to perform some validation before proceeding with an item processing (and optionally discarding it), you can inject the `JdbcTemplate` bean, perform you query to validate your model invariants, then proceed accordingly:

```
public class CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<CaricoDTO, CaricoDTO> {
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private String fileName;
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CaricoDTOItemProcessorStep1.class);
    
    @Override
    public CaricoDTO process(CaricoDTO item) throws Exception {
        boolean someValue = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_other_field = 0", (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getBoolean(0));
        if (someValue) {
            carico.setDataCaricamento(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            carico.setFileName(carico.getResource().getFilename());
            return carico;
        } else {
            return null; // causes the item to be discarded from processing
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say that your query would depend on your domain use-case and needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test your solution.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue!